# MonoBehavior Script that uses UnityEditor - Best practice for Location?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I've created a script which helps me auto-generate a `GameObject` prefab. It uses some `UnityEditor`, so it can't be used at runtime (and its not meant to be).

Normally, a script like this I would put in the "Editor" folder.

However, since it needs to be attached to a `GameObject` as a `Component` to do its thing, I'm not sure where I should put it. I can't store it in the Editor folder, because Unity yells at me and says I'm not allowed.

Are there any best practices defined for things like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**Platform dependent compilation blocks**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) in your scripts, so certain parts would be compiled just if they are in a specific platform. Example:

```
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

public class PrefabCreatorExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string path;

    private void Start()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab(path, GenerateObject());
#endif
    }

    private GameObject GenerateObject()
    {
        GameObject newObject = new GameObject();

        // Your creation logic here...

        return newObject;
    }
}
```

I use this a lot to write Gizmos' attributes for the Editor without generating unnecessary data types on the final build.

You could also use [**Inspector classes**](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector) that will only be compiled on Editor mode, this scrips must be on **Editor**'s folder of course. With this solution you separate the Game's functionality from the Editor's (on this case, I have created the PrefabUtilities MonoBehaviour class). Example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(PrefabUtilities))]
public class PrefabUtilitiesInspector : Editor
{
    private PrefabUtilities prefabUtilities;    /// <summary>Inspector's Target.</summary>

    /// <summary>Sets target property.</summary>
    void OnEnable()
    {
        prefabUtilities = target as PrefabUtilities;
    }

    /// <summary>OnInspectorGUI override.</summary>
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {   
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        if(GUILayout.Button("Substitute with Prefab.")) prefabUtilities.SubstituteGameObjectsForPrefab();
    }
}
```

This would draw a button on the inspector, but you can also do the Editor's exclusive logic there.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I'm doing now. The thing that makes it a bit odd though is that the entire file is only for `UnityEditor`. The entire script gets removed from the GameObject once it's built. I'll probably just keep it like this and put it in some folder that isn't named `Editor`, but named something that makes it obvious it isn't for runtime code.

Answer (score 1):

Myself I'll usually just wrap the whole file in a preprocessor conditional directive block like this:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour {
    // All contents here...
}

#endif
```

That way when I compile a build, the compiler sees the file as effectively empty and skips over it, even if it's not sitting in an Editor folder.